# In Java when one methods in an object is 'synchronized' are all methods 'synchronized'?

Tags: java, multithreading

My understanding is when an object method is 'synchronized', then only one thread is allowed in that method at once.  I tested that and it worked.

But I was told recently that the "lock" that the thread must gain control of to access the synchronized method is an "object lock".  Meaning that all of the methods of the object (synchronized or not) effectively behave in a synchronized manner.

I tested that, with `synchronized void method1();` and `void method2();` and it appears that many threads are able to enter `method2` at the same time.

What is this "object lock" the guy was referring to and how does it work?

Comment: You are right. method2 is not synced in this example.

Answer (score 7):

He meant that if you have two synchronized methods, they will be synchronized amongst each other and not just individually. This is because an object lock is held on the instance the method is called on.

In other words, if you have two synchronized methods `foo()` and `bar()`, no thread can call `bar()` while another thread is calling `foo()`.

This is easy to see if you write out the definition. The synchronized method

```
public synchronized void foo() { 
  stuff;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
public void foo() { 
  synchronized(this) {
    stuff;
  }
}
```

For methods with no associated instance (i.e., static methods), a lock is held on the Class instance instead.

Comment: So if you have two synchronized methods on the same object, only one run can run at the same time (not one of each).